# How to add environment variables in Bitnami virtual machine using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have successfully deployed a NodeJS app using Bitnami and now I would like to add database connection. Following secure practices I would like to add the credentials as environment variables, but I don't know where can I add them permanently.

Right now I run a script to add the environment variables, but I would like them to be available by default.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that adding the exports inside the node command witch is located at: `/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node`

Run this in your SSH terminal:

```
$ sudo nano /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node
```

And then add:

```
export DB_SECRET=1234567890
```

It will add your environment variables always you run `node app.js`. It also works with `forever start app.js` since forever runs inside that file.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add them in

```
sudo nano /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh
```

I'm still looking into this, ideally you don't store credentials in any file on the machine.